# How to add multiple geojsons to a geochoropleth in dc.js?

Tags: d3.js, geojson, dc.js, choropleth

I'm trying to create a geochoropleth that maps subregions, but also includes outlines of larger regions.  (You can think of it like mapping counties, but then wanting to include thicker outlines of states).  Not all subregions are part of larger regions that need to be outlined.  (Most aren't.) You can see an example of what I'm trying to replicate here:[image: Example outlines.]

What's the best way to add this regional outline to my map?  I've tried keeping the regions and subregions as two separate files, with two overlaygeojsons calls in my geochoropleth call (with added d3 styling to change the fill and stroke to just be an outline).  But when I do - the projection of the regional outline layer is strangely offset from the lower one.[image: Offset second geojson]

I've also considered having both sets of boundaries in just the one geojson.  However, I wasn't sure how to work with this.

While it would be nice to be able to mouseover the boundaries of the larger regions and get a tooltip before crossing over into the individual subregions and getting their tooltips, this isn't a must.  I could live with just outlines around the regions.  Please advise on the best way to do this.  Happy to provide more detail, and thanks so much!

EDIT: I discovered that I had a misplaced transform tag which is what offset the second layer. Fixed now!

Comment: Sounds like you are reporting a bug, rather than asking a question. It's pretty clear that [overlayGeoJson](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/GeoChoroplethChart.html#overlayGeoJson__anchor) is supposed to handle multiple layers; the docs specifically mention the layers may be on top of each other. Not sure why it would be offset... strange interactivity might be due to mouse events going to both layers. Would help to have an example to look at, if possible.

Comment: *While it would be nice to be able to mouseover the boundaries of the larger regions and get a tooltip before crossing over into the individual subregions and getting their tooltips, this isn't a must.* This doesn't make sense to me - if I mouseover a large region I must be doing mouseover on a small region. How do you decide the tooltip ? Surely you just have a tooltip that includes attributes e.g. large region name, small region name, fact1, fact2, fact2 etc etc

Comment: Added image of second geojson offset to post, to illustrate the problem.

And I was hoping that the tooltip would trigger on the outline layer, when only mousing over the border path.

Comment: Glad you figured out the transform issue. I don't have time to work up an independent example in order to try stuff, but it sounds like you might be able to do what you want by adjusting the SVG `stroke-width` independently for each layer using CSS? However, I don't know of any easy way to keep the stroke inside each shape, so there may be an overlap issue where two regions abut.